# C - Why can I use a function from another source file without including the source file?

Tags: c, function, include, header-files

Good Morning,

What I have is the following:

```
//Simulator.h
#ifndef SIMULATOR_H
#define SIMULATOR_H

inline void functionn1(void);
#endif
```

Then I have it's implementation:

```
//Simulator.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "simulator.h"

inline void functionn1(void){printf("Functionn 1\n");}
```

And finally the main program:

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "simulator.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
functionn1();
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It works as expected but after playing around with it I noticed that:

1. It also works when I comment out the function prototype from Simulator.h
2. Furthermore when I comment out the function prototype AND purposefully NOT include Simulator.h in the main.c the function still works.

Why does it work after I do the two steps above ? What kind of shennanigans is going on here ?

Comment: Have you tried to compile with -Wall option? It will gives you  `warning: implicit declaration of function `

Comment: If you you use a reasonably recent standard such as C99 it shouldn't work anymore. When you write ´functionn3` you mean `functionn1`, no?

Comment: because you are actually calling functionn3() instead. The definition of functionn1 is irrelevant.

Comment: @LPs - I'm using NetBeans IDE

Comment: @MOehm - Yes I meant functionn1 it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical reasons, C would also work without any function prototypes. The downside is that there will be no parameter checking.

As long as there is an object file that exports your function, the linker will know how to put the pieces together.

Comment: After reading your answer I've done a bit of research and found that using the keyword **static** prevents the behavior in my original question, would that be the most optimal way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. If you declare a function static in C it will only be known within the source file that it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

When the C parser meets a function usage and it doesn't know anything about this function, it generates a dummy signature and goes on.

The linker will try to find the appropriate symbol (i.e. find a symbol with the function's name in any code object / library passed to the linker), which appears to be present in your case.

You usually get a warning for this, as it can lead to several bugs: the automatically generated function is assumed to return an int. If a pointer is actually returned and `sizeof(int) != sizeof(intptr_t)` you'll get a subtle bug as the adress wil be... truncated.

For instance the following does compile

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  return foo();
}
```

(and might run into a linker error if `foo` is not defined in another compilation unit), but the following does *not* compile:

```
struct test {};
// missing declaration:
// struct test foo();
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  // foo is not available, it defaults to returning an int
  struct test t = foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Because the conversion from the implicit return type `int` to `struct test` is invalid.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I don't understand what your last example with the structure is meant to convey- it's not going to work because you have genuine syntax errors trying to assign a return value from a function to your empty structure, how is that relevant ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer : it assumes `foo` returns a `struct test`. As the declaration is not available, it defaults to a function returing an int, which is incorrect; I've update the code to show this.